# Getting weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:getNewTla exception. How to resolve this?

Tags: performance, unix, testing, weblogic11g

```
Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '95' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default  (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:getNewTla at   weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.timerExpired(SessionContext.java:889)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

I have tried to resolve this issue by increasing memory size and perm gen size both in setDomainEnv.sh. It works fine for around 500 requests but after that it is giving this error and server's health is changed from OK to Warning in console. How to resolve this... ?

Comment: I'm reading that like Weblogic is running out of Three Letter Acronyms, which feels rather appropriate for IBM…

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the TLA size with the arguments `-XXtlasize:min=8k,preferred=128k`.

This blog post was helpful https://blogs.oracle.com/pa/entry/error_java_lang_outofmemoryerror_getnewtla